# What is `Virtuality` in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I recently update `phpmyadmin` and now I have this new option called `Virtuality` when adding a new column.

```
[Virtuality]
>VIRTUAL
>STORED
```

What is this used for and when should it be used?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

column that is **automatically computed** (example: 'age' column):

```
CREATE TABLE users
( 
  birth_year   NUMBER(15,2) 
, death_year   NUMBER(15,2)
, age          NUMBER(15,2) AS (death_year - birth_year)
);
```

Comment: Perhaps you could cover the third option `persistent`

Answer (score 8):

> VIRTUAL: Column values are not stored, but are evaluated when rows are
>   read, immediately after any BEFORE triggers. A virtual column takes no
>   storage. -- MySQL Reference
>
> STORED: Column values are evaluated and stored when rows are inserted or updated. A stored column does require storage space and
>   can be indexed. -- MySQL Reference

*The default is VIRTUAL if neither keyword is specified.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html